# Irrationality of $ \pi e, \pi^{\pi}$ and $e^{\pi^2}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, irrational-numbers

What is known about irrationality of $\pi e$, $\pi^\pi$ and $e^{\pi^2}$?

Comment: Why are you interested in these particular numbers?

Comment: I recently asked a similar question - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33817/work-on-independence-of-pi-and-e

Comment: No doubt that a proof of irrationality of one of these numbers would be a monument of the human intelligence... But isn't a bit sad, such a big effort to prove something that everybody would believe true? What I would really like to see is a proof of *rationality* of at least one of these combinations of $\pi$ $e$ and $\gamma$.

Comment: Pietro, why would it be sad to prove something people believe?  It happens all the time! More often than not (but not always) long-standing conjectures which are solved turn out to be true in the way that they were conjectured. 

Comment: Pietro said that it would be sad if effort were put into such things (rather than into something more enlightening or useful). I agree.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Don't you think that the rationality of $\pi e$ would be very enlightening and useful? 

Comment: Irrationality proofs generally aren't useful in any practical sense, but they can certainly be enlightening.

Comment: A similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386207/what-is-the-role-of-mathematical-intuition-and-common-sense-in-questions-of-irra

Comment: If an oracle told you that exactly one of these is rational, which would you bet on?

Comment: If someone proves that $\pi^\pi$ is irrational, the interesting statement is not "$\pi^\pi$ is irrational" but "humans (or computers) can prove that  $\pi^\pi$ is irrational". The first statement is expected, the second statement is unexpected and absolutely amazing.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I believe most such questions are still very far from being resolved.

Apparently, it is not even known if $\pi^{\pi^{\pi^\pi}}$ is an integer (let alone irrational).

Comment: You raise a nice question! (Though of course an answer 'yes'
would be a lot nicer than 'no'!)

Comment: @Oksana Gimmel: very interesting!  Can you suggest any references for reading on that last bit?  (It’s rather difficult to search about!)

Comment: It is mentioned on the Russian Wikipedia page [Open mathematical problems](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B#.D0.92.D0.BE.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.8B_.D0.B8.D1.80.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8). A very similar question was discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13050/eee79-and-ultrafinitism

Comment: Surely it can be proven that pi^pi^pi^pi is not an integer? Just bound it between two consecutive integers... It would be inelegant as factorial but it would work ?

Comment: @Oliver But what if it is actually an integer?

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Then we would fail, and be unable to bound it between two consecutive integers. But that (probably) won't happen.. just get a computer to find a good enough upper and lower bound, which would count as a proof.

Comment: ok, pi^pi^pi^pi is a hell of a lot bigger than I thought it was. Should still work though if you have a good computer and enough time.

Comment: @Oliver Even if we had such a computer, and got a result like `435643…85685.00000000000…`, how do we know if it is the exact integer, or we just need higher precision to discover non-zero fractional part?

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Oh, if it actually is an integer then of course this wouldn't work. I'm assuming it's not an integer. (I see no reason why we would get `x.00000000000...`)

Comment: $\pi^{\pi^{\pi^{\pi}}}$ has over a hundred quadrillion digits.  It would take more than two exabytes of storage just to write down the integer part of that number.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov In that case you can run two programs in parallel: one obtaining higher and higher precision of the said number, and the other enumerate all valid proofs and see if one is a proof that the said number is an integer. I bet the first program terminate first.

Comment: @FanZheng It's still possible that none of the programs terminates, because of incompleteness (there are true statements without proofs).

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov OK, after putting it in wolframalpha, I realized like LTS above that it is *much* larger than I had thought... so your scenario may well be true, at least *in practice*.

Comment: as well as in theory, which I of course believe. To put it more concretely, you need to compute at least $10^{17}$ digits of $\pi$ in order to tell if that number is an integer, and the best approximation of $\pi$ that I'm aware of gives $10^{12}$ digits. There's still someway to go.

Answer (score 102):

Brownawell and Waldschmidt do have results in these directions which do not rely on Schanuel's Conjecture.  The references are

M. Waldschmidt, "Solution du Huitième Problème de Schneider," J. Number Theory 5 (1973), 191-202.

W. D. Brownawell, "The algebraic independence of certain numbers related by the exponential function," J. Number Theory 6 (1974), 23-31.

The two papers independently prove results along the following lines. (The following version is taken from Brownawell.) Let $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ be nonzero complex numbers with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ both irrational.  If $e^\gamma$ and $e^{\alpha\gamma}$ are both algebraic numbers, then at least two of the numbers $$\alpha, \beta, \gamma, e^{\beta\gamma}, e^{\alpha\beta\gamma}$$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

This theorem has several interesting consequences:

- Taking $\alpha=\beta=e^{-1}, \gamma=e^2$, we see that at least one of $e^e$ and $e^{e^2}$ must be transcendental.  This was conjectured by Schneider.
- Taking $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$, we see that given any nonzero complex number $\alpha$, at least one of the numbers $e^{\alpha}, e^{\alpha^2}, e^{\alpha^3}$ must be transcendental.
- Taking $\alpha = \beta = i/\pi, \gamma=\pi^2$, we see that at least one of the following holds: (i) $e^{\pi^2}$ is transcendental, or (ii) $e$ and $\pi$ are algebraically independent.

So as a partial answer to this question, at least one of $e\pi$ and $e^{\pi^2}$ is transcendental.