# Is it possible to know if $\log(\pi)$ is irrational or not since the $\log$ function is the inverse of the $\exp$ function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory, irrational-numbers

I'm interested in knowing more about the question if $f(\pi)$ is rational or not, where $f$ is some well-known function. For example, $\cos(\pi) =-1$ is rational, while ${e}^{\pi}$ is irrational as shown [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%28pi%29++is+irrational+number) by WolframAlpha.

**My question here is**: Is it possible to know if $\log(\pi)$ is rational or not since the $\log$ function is the inverse of the $\exp$ function?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I don't think this is known. If $\log(\pi)=p/q$, then $e^p=\pi^q$, which implies  that $\pi$ and $e$ are algebraically dependent. It is widely believed, but not proved, that $\pi$ and $e$ are algebraically independent.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33817/work-on-independence-of-pi-and-e/33820#33820

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The irrationality of $\log \pi$ is an open problem (see for example [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3253) recent paper).

It is expected to be transcendental (page 34 of [this slides](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/TNTOpenPbs.pdf) by Michel Waldschmidt), and in fact this follows from Schanuel's conjecture (this is referenced [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.6216), beginning of section 3), which is widely believed to be true.

In particular, to answer the question in the title, it does not follows from the irrationality (or transcendence) of $e^\pi$ by any known argument.

Comment: Thank you for citing my arXiv paper. In fact, I've investigated the number ln(pi) more closely in my recent paper published in Journal of Analysis and Number Theory 5, p.91 (2017). The title is "Some Transcendence Results from a Harmless Irrationality Theorem". There you will find some nice discussions on irrationality and transcendence of many numbers. Regards, Prof. Fabio M. S. Lima

Comment: The paper is freely available at http://www.naturalspublishing.com/files/published/j2s8h5c33e8ci4.pdf It does not settle the question of $\log\pi$

Comment: I note that Natural Sciences Publishing Corporation is on a list of possibly predatory publishers maintained at https://predatoryjournals.com/publishers .

Comment: Hi Gerry Myerson,  you are right, the irrationality of ln(pi) remains open. However, according to my Theorem 3, at least 2 of the 3 numbers {pi+e, pi*e, ln(pi)} are TRANSCENDENTAL. I think this gets a sensation that ln(pi) must be transcendental. More work in this direction is needed...

Comment: Let me take this opportunity to say that judge a paper by the name of the journal in which it was published, without reading the paper, is bad.  I've chosen JANT by the scope, not by fame!