# Is there a fixed integer $n$ for which the difference :$\pi^n-\ e ^n$ is integer number?

Tags: nt.number-theory, integer-sequences, transcendental-number-theory, irrational-numbers

I'm interested knowing more about nature of $\pi$ and $\ e$ since they are independent algebraically.

In this question I'm interested to know if there exist a integer $n$ for which the difference $\pi^n-\ e ^n$ is an integer number.

**Note:** even now I got an approach values of the difference $\pi^n-\ e ^n$ for $n=6 $ using [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%5E6-e%5E6&wal=header) which it is  closed to $558$ .

Thank you for any help

Comment: It is a wide open problem in transcendental number theory to prove the algebraic independence of $e$ and $\pi$. Even proving irrationality of $\pi - e$ has resisted all attempts so far. It doesn't appear to me that proving that $\pi^n - e^n$ is never a rational integer would be any easier than this well known unsolved problem.

Comment: sorry for that , i think it's not open

Comment: @user51189.  According to your first sentence the polynomial equation $f(X,Y)=X^n-Y^n+m=0$ when substituted by $\pi$ and $e$ will not be satisfied. So the question contradictst your first sentence. If you think a problem is closed, you must be aware someone has settled it and you should make the whole world know about this.

Comment: If you think it's not open, then you think the answer is known. Now why would you think that?

Comment: "close to 558" (i.e. approximately 557.96...)?  Sure, for any particular integer nonzero $n$ you can presumably compute $\pi^n - e^n$ numerically with sufficient accuracy to show that this particular one is not an integer.  That tells you nothing about whether it will be an integer for some $n$ that you haven't tried yet.

Comment: Oh, by the way, you might try $n=0$.

Comment: n=0 is trivial  case , i forget to avoid it in the titled question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim that $\pi$ and $e$ are known to be algebraically independent is incorrect, see for example [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33817/work-on-independence-of-pi-and-e).

The rationality of $\pi^n-e^n$ is a well-known open problem alredy for $n=1$, and there's no reason to suspect that the $n>1$ case should be any easier.

Not sure if you can find a direct reference for the problem with arbitrary $n$ (for the reason above), but if the result was known it would be a huge deal, and it would be in about every survey on transcendence theory (since there's not that many known results to brag about).