# About $\pi$, $e$ and transcendence

Tags: transcendental-number-theory

This is mostly curiosity on my part.  I assume  experts would have  some  up-to-date info.

1. Are $1$, $\pi$ and $e$ linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$?
2. Does the set $\{ m\pi+ne;\;\;m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ contain any algebraic numbers?

Thanks.

Comment: see https://mathoverflow.net/q/33817/11260

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I checked that question before I posed mine. I do not  understand  what Wilkie's work has to do with the specific question. I am quite familiar with 0-minimality.  Then I asked about *linear* independence.

Comment: on a trivial note, the set $\{ m\pi+ne;\;\;m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}, m^2+n^2 \ne 0$ can contain at most one algebraic number with $(m,n) =1$ of course and $mn \ne 0$ for any such

Answer (score 9):

Almost certainly $1, \pi, e$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$, and also over the algebraic numbers (so in particular the only algebraic number in your set $\{m\pi + n e: m,n \in \mathbb Z\}$ is $0$ which comes from $m=n=0$).  This would follow from Schanuel's conjecture, I think.  But it is only a conjecture: we don't even know that $e  + \pi$ is irrational.

Comment: Yes, Schanuel's conjecture implies that $\{ 1, i \pi, e, e^{i \pi} \}$ has transcendence degree 2, so $e$ and $\pi$ are algebraically independent (which is stronger than linear independence over the algebraic numbers).